# SignalR with Asp.net MVC 4.0 in VS2010

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am new to SignalR and I'm following [this article](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc-4) on running SignalR with MVC 4.0 on VS2010.

I have added the required references using the package manager. However I am unable 
to add a call to the method RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs() as the MapHubs option is not available. What references I am missing?

These are the references I have in my project now:

```
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client  
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core 
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin
```

Am I missing something else?

Comment: If you're using SignalR 1.1.3 then those instructions will work. If you're using 2.0 rc1 then you need to look at this http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/upgrading-signalr-1x-projects-to-20. Also, when you install the Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR  package, a readme opens with specific instructions telling you how to get started

Comment: when I try to install 2.0 using nuget I get an error saying that my project is in .net 4.0 so I selected 1.1.3 in nuget. I am not able to get the method RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs() That article doesnt seem to mention every step for .net 4.0 in VS2010 like it does for .net 4.5 in VS2012

Comment: If you're using 1.1.3 (and you have to because you're using .NET 4.0) and you install Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR it will bring in everything required to hook it up. If you manually installed other packages (like the list you have above) you'll have a hard time finding the right methods.